# running lua programs from cmd

Tags: lua, cmd

I'm looking to run lua code in the Command Prompt from windows. Its in windows 7 but it can run on Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8. Please tell me if there is a way to or how to be able to do it.

Comment: Download and install LUA. You can get it from here: http://www.lua.org/download.html or try this one: https://code.google.com/p/luaforwindows/

Comment: simply use the lua interpreter. More info at http://www.lua.org/pil/1.4.html (anything but the two first examples are also appliable under windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lua.exe myscript.lua`. You can [download and build Lua yourself](http://www.lua.org/download.html) or get [Lua binaries for Windows](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html).

Comment: thank you but im looking for is a command for the cmd in windows so something like

Comment: That's not a standard Lua interpreter then. Any arguments after `location` are arguments to the script itself.

Comment: well no but it could be "lua [run : edit : debug [true : false]] [Location] [arguments]

Comment: I have no idea what run/edit/debug mean in this particular context. If you want to be able to edit, run, and debug Lua applications, you may want to try something like [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com) I've been developing.